# Are the Exchange 2007 hub transport rule predicates any-style or all-style

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I really could not think of a better way to express the Any|All distinction I am trying to make there. If you can, please go right ahead.

I am trying to make a rule for an exchange hub transport server to block based on external address. This is mainly to kill the mail loops that have appeared when, for instance, our ticketing system gets into a looped discussion with some external ticket system.

I have only just started to take on the role of server admin and I am grossly unqualified. I just happen to be the developer remaining in the IT department when the Sysadmin left. So please excuse any derpiness on my part.

We do not have any servers with the edge transport role installed and we won't be getting into installing a whole new server role here.

Right now I have just one address I want to block, but I am sure I will want more, and I do not want a rule-per blocked address situation. So far what I have is:

```
when the From address contains badaddress@otherdomain.com
log an event with Email blocked due to sender address
and silently drop message
```

but in making this I noticed that the parameter for the predicate is multivalued - that is, I can put as many 'words' as I want in to match against the From address. What I can't find any info on is - how will this be evaluated? I know I could get something I know works the way I want it using text patterns but it will be messy with multiple addresses.

Anyway, hopefully this is a really simple question and I've got enough context there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in the `Addresses` predicate property is treated as a collection in which a match is to be found. In the context you've given, it is definitely an "Any" match evaluation